# Grant application access to UAC protected registry section

Tags: uac, registry, installshield-2010

I have a legacy USB device driver which reads and writes data from and to the Windows registry to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE/COMPANY/PRODUCT. 
I am not able to change this so I need a workaround because I noticed that on Windows Vista and Windows 7 with UAC enabled the function that performs the write returns an error. My guess is that is simply has no access rights.

My current workaround is to launch my application with administrative privileges but as you might guess this is not a very nice solution. Since the registry is accessed when the USB device is initialized when the application starts I also cannot simply request a relaunch.

I know that I can give access rights to certain folders on the system with cacls from my installer (which runs with administrative privileges) but is there something similar I can do to grant this to this specific registry entry? (I would like both grant and revoke commands.)

Answer (score 0):

Giving non-admin users write permissions to HKLM should be avoided. If you still need to do it, however, you could use [SetACL](http://helgeklein.com/setacl/) to set/remove permissions. SetACL is available as a standalone command-line executable and as a COM object.